# FileNotFoundException coming from Java web application

Tags: java, file-io, relative-path, fileinputstream

I am working on the web application with Eclipse. I have created one property file for database configuration. (DBProperty.properties)
Please find below screen-shot of the folder structure.

[image]

I want to access this property file.  I am accessing with below code.

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("src/resources/DBProperty.properties");
```

I have also tried many relative paths but not able to succeed.

I have set build path for this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("DBProperty.properties")
```

Comment: Thanks. It works with getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream().

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("resources/DBProperty.properties");
```

Please try the above line of code. Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `src` directory isn't there at runtime.
2. Resources are not files.

You need to look into `Class.getResource()` and friends.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify complete file path with File object.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    File file = new File("C:\\Path\\workspace\\jbossmqimpl\\Test1\\resources\\NewFile.xml");

    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {

        System.out.println("Total file size to read (in bytes) : "+ fis.available());

        int content;
        while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
            // convert to char and display it
            System.out.print((char) content);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```